# What is the power tier of the Battle Sorcerer variant from UA?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class

What is the approximate power tier of the Battle Sorcerer variant from UA?

I know regular sorcerers are generally accepted as Tier 2.... I’d imagine that Battle Sorcerers drop to Tier 3 due to diminished spell-casting and becoming MAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tier 2.

The battle sorcerer is distinctly worse than the sorcerer—fewer spells per day, fewer spells known, and all you get in return is +2 hp and +¼ BAB per level on average.

But you still have 9th-level spells from the fantastic sorcerer/wizard list—that’s good enough for tier 2. Probably the bottom of tier 2, but still there.